# How to get the value of the last by the client checked checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I am making a parrent meeting webapplication but i have a problem. First you select a teacher to go to a table where you can see which appointments are still free.
That table is filled with checkboxes where the parrents can select a time for when they want their appointment. All the occupied times have their checkboxes disabled.


This is the code i use for my checkboxes:

```html
 <table width="1100" border="1">
<tr>
 <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">Tijdstip</th>
 <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">Bezet?</b></th>
 <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">Commentaar</b></th>
</tr>
 <form method = "post" action = "toevoegen.php">
  <?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($bezet)) { ?>

  <tr>
       <td><?php echo $record['start']; echo " "; echo $record['einde'];?></td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    $teller = $teller+1;
    ?>
  <input type='checkbox' name='bezet' id='bezet' value="<?php $record['sequence'] ?>" onChange="this.form.submit(this)"
          
   <?php if($record['bezet'] == 1 && $record['leerkracht_id'] == $_SESSION['lk']){ ?>
    checked="checked"
    disabled="disabled"
      <?php } ?>
        />
     </td>
  <td><?php if($record['bezet'] == 1 && $record['leerkracht_id'] == $_SESSION['lk']){ 
    echo "Bezet";
           
      } ?></td>
    </tr>
      <?php  } ?>
 </form>
</table>
```

When u click on the checkbox you get redirected to the next page where you fill in your name and the name of your child. Now to get the application to work properly i would have to get the value of the by the parrent checked checkbox to dissalble the checkbox on the last page so no one else can take that time.


How would i be able to do this?
Anny help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can post your form with get method on new page. Here you can get values in the URL by $_GET;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').last().val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked value="1">
<input type="checkbox" checked value="2">
```

Comment: The question says [tag:php], not [tag:javascript]

Comment: i have to get the by the parrent selected checkbox not the last one of the checkboxes.